# How to convert world raycaster intersaction coordinates to "matrix" coordinates in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, coordinates, raycasting

**Hi! I faced a tricky task that I can't solve for a long time.
I will be very grateful for your help!**

## Description:

I create a threejs plane. Plane for the future game. I set the size of the plane based on the **chunkSize** parameter. Also i have another object, let's call it a player, that moves on our plane. I'm using a PerspectiveCamera which follows the player's position.
When I click on a plane, I want to determine to which "imaginary matrix" coordinate belongs this world coordinate (intersaction coordinate).

Let's say the **ChunkSize** parameter is **10**, which means I have an imaginary **10x10 matrix**. So when i click on **left-top corner of the plane**, I want to get the **coordinate in the matrix (0,0)**, and when click on the **right-bottom corner of the plane - (9, 9) coordinate**

## Setup the scene

Added there a little description too

```
// 1. Create scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


// 2. Create our Plane
const chunkSize = 10;
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(chunkSize, chunkSize);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
plane.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
scene.add(plane);


// 3. Create our object
const objectGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const objectMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
const object = new THREE.Mesh(objectGeometry, objectMaterial);
scene.add(object);

// 4. Raycaster for intersaction and mouse vector for mouse calculation
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
});


// 5. Render function
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  // 5.1 Move the object
  object.position.x = Math.sin(performance.now() * 0.0001) * 4;
  object.position.z = Math.cos(performance.now() * 0.0001) * 4;

  // 5.2 Move camera (so our worldCoordToMatrix function has to return right coords in any camera position)
  // Also important that i dont change lookAt vector
  const cameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(-4, 4, 4);
  camera.position.copy(object.position).add(cameraOffset);

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);

  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    const intersectionPoint = intersects[0].point;
    // 5.3 Calc matrix coords
    const matrixCoords = worldCoordToMatrix(...);
    console.log(`Matrix coordinates: x = ${matrixCoords.x}, z = ${matrixCoords.z}`);
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

## This the example of function which work correct only if camera looks straight on the plain:

```
export const worldCoordToMatrix = (worldSize: number, coordinate: Coordinate) => {
    const sqsize = (worldSize - 1) / 2
    return {
        x: Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(coordinate.x + sqsize), 0), worldSize-1),
        z: Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(coordinate.z + sqsize), 0), worldSize-1)
    }
}
```

I assume that the function should take the camera coordinate and the coordinate of our object in order to correctly calculate the coordinates, however, my knowledge of mathematics is not enough to get a working version

`worldCoordToMatrix = (worldSize: number, coordinate: THREE.Vector3, cameraPosition: THREE.Vector3, objectPosition: THREE.Vector3) => number`

## In coclusion, I need to create **worldCoordsToMatrix** function, which will return right matrix coordinates in any camera position

I ll be very glad if ull help me!
Also i have created [CodePen](https://codepen.io/denkravchu/pen/BaqJJMv?editors=0111) with threejs and scene setup template for ur convenient
[Link to CodePan with template](https://codepen.io/denkravchu/pen/BaqJJMv?editors=0111)

I also tortured СhatGPT 4.0 for 2-3 hours but didnt get a working version

Comment: Maybe this example will help: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_raycaster_texture.html